Writing Data to Excel using Interop c#
I am able to write data to excel with the help of Interop in .Net Core but is there any way by which it is possible that it will not change the existing excel template.
Actually I have an excel template and for multiple users, I want to have the different excel data but my code is writing data to my main file which I don't want.
Please help me with this scenario.
I have used the following code to write:
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//Microsoft Excel 16 object in references-> COM tab
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Application xlApp = new Application();
float Left;
float Top;
string FilePath = DefaultImagesPath;

Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName);
_Worksheet xlWorksheet = (_Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

xlWorksheet.Cells[5, 5] = "text";

//For Image
Excel.Range primaryOkImageRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[20, 15];
Left = (float)((double)primaryOkImageRange.Left);
Top = (float)((double)primaryOkImageRange.Top);
xlWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(FilePath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 
Left, Top, 50, 50);

xlApp.Visible = false;
xlApp.UserControl = false;

//cleanup
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
//close and release
xlWorkbook.Close();
//quit and release
xlApp.Quit();

What i have tried to clear the existing value:
var rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[5, 5];
Left = (float)((double)rng.Left);
Top = (float)((double)rng.Top);
rng.Cells.Clear();

But this is not working.

If you do not want to modify the original file, then create a copy? The intended behavior is not really clear to me.

@JonasH I just do not want to alter the existing template, actually my code is writing data to the existing template. Suppose there is a value which exists for UserA but not available to UserB. If the excel is generated for UserB, that value must not be visible to UserB because that value is related only to UserA.

Are you asking how to create a new document from an existing template, and then modify that document using interop?

@JonasH Yes It will work for me.

Hi I want to thanks JonasH for providing the idea. Just did the following change and my scenario is now successful.
 if (File.Exists(DestinationFileName))
 {
 File.Delete(DestinationFileName);
 }

 File.Copy(SourceFileName, DestinationFileName, true);
 Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(DestinationFileName);

